# Setting an object's property in another procedure

Tags: delphi, checkbox, boolean

I have an object that has some properties:

```
Obj.Big
Obj.Rotate
Obj.Paint
Obj.Lines
```

etc. They are all boolean type properties.

In my main procedure, I call another procedure:

```
procedure TMainForm.Create(Sender:TObject);
begin
     SetParameter(BigCheckBox, Obj.Big);
     SetParameter(RotateCheckBox, Obj.Rotate);
     SetParameter(PaintCheckBox, Obj.Paint);
     SetParameter(LinesCheckBox, Obj.Lines);
end;
```

The `SetParameter` procedure goes like this:

```
procedure TMainForm.SetParameter(ACheckBox : TCheckBox; ABoolOption : Boolean);
begin
    if(ACheckBox.Checked) and (ACheckBox.Enabled) then begin
      ABoolOption := true;
    end
    else if(not ACheckBox.Checked) and (ACheckBox.Enabled) then begin
      ABoolOption := false;
    end;
end;
```

It accepts the checkbox object and the property of the passed object's boolean property as `ABoolOption`. I cannot simple do `LinesCheckBox.Checked := Obj.Lines` because I need to have a "do nothing" action when the checkbox is filled (they are all tri-state). When I run this, none of those object's parameters are changed. Why is this?

Comment: it would not change even if you would pass a simple variable. read about `out-parameters` and `var-parameters`. You procedure gets a value and may change it whatever it wants - it would never go outside of the procedure body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not passing the property. You're  passing the *value* of that property. IOW, your `SetParameter` is receiving `ACheckBox, True` or `ACheckBox, False`, and therefore there's nothing for you to change. The better way might be to change your `SetParameter` procedure to a function:

```
function TMainForm.SetBooleanValue(const ACheckBox: TCheckBox): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (ACheckBox.Checked) and (ACheckBox.Enabled);
end;
```

And then use it like:

```
Obj.Big := SetBooleanValue(BigCheckbox);
Obj.Rotate := SetBooleanValue(RotateCheckBox);
Obj.Paint := SetBooleanValue(PaintCheckBox);
Obj.Lines := SetBooleanValue(LinesCheckBox);
```

If you need to allow for a third option, you should check it first before performing the call to `SetBooleanValue`:

```
if not ThirdCondition then
  Obj.Big := SetBooleanValue(BigCheckBox);
```

Comment: i used `BigCheckBox.State = cbGrayed` as the if not statement comparative and set the object's properties in the main procedure and used the result of the function to do the set. this all works now. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure does not do what you think it does.  You are *NOT* passing the property itself, you are passing the *CURRENT VALUE* of the property instead.  If you want to actually update the value of the property, you need to either do what Ken suggests, or use RTTI instead, eg:

```
uses
  ..., TypInfo;

procedure TMainForm.Create(Sender:TObject);
begin
  SetBooleanParameter(BigCheckBox, Obj, 'Big');
  SetBooleanParameter(RotateCheckBox, Obj, 'Rotate');
  SetBooleanParameter(PaintCheckBox, Obj, 'Paint');
  SetBooleanParameter(LinesCheckBox, Obj, 'Lines');
end;

procedure TMainForm.SetBooleanParameter(ACheckBox : TCheckBox; Obj: TObject; const PropName: String);
begin
  if ACheckBox.Enabled then begin
    // NOTE: this only works if the properties are declared as 'published'
    SetOrdProp(Obj, PropName, Ord(ACheckBox.Checked));
  end;
end;
```

Or, if you are using D2010+:

```
uses
  ..., Rtti;

procedure TMainForm.Create(Sender:TObject);
begin
  SetBooleanParameter(BigCheckBox, Obj, 'Big');
  SetBooleanParameter(RotateCheckBox, Obj, 'Rotate');
  SetBooleanParameter(PaintCheckBox, Obj, 'Paint');
  SetBooleanParameter(LinesCheckBox, Obj, 'Lines');
end;

procedure TMainForm.SetBooleanParameter(ACheckBox : TCheckBox; Obj: TObject; const PropName: String);
var
  Ctx: TRttiContext;
begin
  if ACheckBox.Enabled then
  begin
    // NOTE: this approach does not need the properties to be declared as 'published'
    Ctx.GetType(Obj.ClassType).GetProperty(PropName).SetValue(Obj, TValue.From<Boolean>(ACheckBox.Checked));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Why call TRttiContext.Create and then ctx.Free?

Comment: @DavidHeffernen: Old habits.